# I'm trying to use qv2ray but it keeps V2Ray core executable not found

Tags: vpn

I installed qv2ray from snap and I'm completely new to Ubuntu, I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

first download the *V2ray core* from this [GitHub Link][1]
[1]: https://github.com/v2fly/v2ray-core
extract the zip file.
go to the **qv2ray app, > preferences > Kernel setting : V2Ray core Executable and select the directory of your *V2Ray core***